# ¿Cómo pedir permiso para compartir/grabar mi pestaña actual con los mediaDevices en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web similar a "Google Meet" en la que las personas pueden grabar reuniones. Para obtener el video o la pantalla de mi navegador, estoy utilizando el siguiente código como ejemplo:

```js
const videoElem = document.getElementById("video");
const logElem = document.getElementById("log");
const startElem = document.getElementById("start");
const stopElem = document.getElementById("stop");

// Opciones para getDisplayMedia()
const displayMediaOptions = {
    video: {
        displaySurface: "browser",
        logicalSurface: true,
        preferCurrentTab: true
    },
    audio: false,
};

// Establecer detectores de eventos para los botones de inicio y detención
startElem.addEventListener(
    "click",
    (evt) => {
        startCapture();
    },
    false,
);

stopElem.addEventListener(
    "click",
    (evt) => {
        stopCapture();
    },
    false,
);

console.log = (msg) => (logElem.textContent = `${logElem.textContent}\n${msg}`);
console.error = (msg) =>
    (logElem.textContent = `${logElem.textContent}\nError: ${msg}`);

async function startCapture() {
    logElem.innerHTML = "";

    try {
        // Solicitar permiso para la captura de pantalla
        await navigator.permissions.query({ name: "display-capture" });

        // Luego, obtener la captura de pantalla
        videoElem.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
        dumpOptionsInfo();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

function stopCapture(evt) {
    let tracks = videoElem.srcObject.getTracks();

    tracks.forEach((track) => track.stop());
    videoElem.srcObject = null;
}

function dumpOptionsInfo() {
    const videoTrack = videoElem.srcObject.getVideoTracks()[0];

    console.log("Ajustes de pista:");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(videoTrack.getSettings(), null, 2));
    console.log("Restricciones de pista:");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(videoTrack.getConstraints(), null, 2));
}
```

```css
#video {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    width: 98%;
    max-width: 860px;
}

#log {
    width: 25rem;
    height: 15rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body id="container">
    <p>
        Este ejemplo le muestra el contenido de la parte seleccionada de su pantalla.
        Haga clic en el botón Iniciar captura para comenzar.
    </p>

    <p>
        <button id="start">Iniciar captura</button>&nbsp;<button id="stop">
            Detener captura
        </button>
    </p>

    <video id="video" autoplay></video>
    <br />

    <strong>Registro:</strong>
    <br />
    <pre id="log"></pre>
      <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Cuando presiono el botón "Iniciar captura", se me presentan varias opciones, como se muestra en la imagen a continuación:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, deseo que la opción de captura se limite exclusivamente a compartir la pestaña actual y no permita seleccionar otras opciones o áreas de captura, como se muestra en la imagen a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo lograr este comportamiento? Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda proporcionada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está la opción [preferCurrentTab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia#prefercurrenttab) que según la documentación es experimental y seguramente no en todos los navegadores se comporta igual, pero al menos los basados en Chrome hace exactamente lo que tu quieres.

Tu lo tienes mal puesto en la configuración de opciones, debería ser:

```
const displayMediaOptions = {
    video: {
        displaySurface: "browser",
        logicalSurface: true
    },
    preferCurrentTab: true,
    audio: false,
};
```

Notar que `preferCurrentTab` va al mismo nivel que `video` y `audio`, **NO** dentro de `video` como lo tienes tu

Yo lo probé en Edge y funciona, fijate que en la siguiente imagen tengo varias pestañas abiertas y solo me permite seleccionar una sola que es la de la aplicación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -4):

Lo más sencillo que te puedo explicar es que busques codigo para iniciar la cámara, directamente pedirá permisos y si son aceptados, lo muestra, pero si no, no lo muestra, este es un codigo html que me ha generado la IA, ya que en mis programas no utilizo ni cámara ni micrófono, luego **Acomoda el codigo**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #camera {
      display: none;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background: #f0f0f0 url("camera-icon-gray.png") center no-repeat;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function initializeCamera() {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then(function(stream) {
          var videoElement = document.getElementById("camera");
          videoElement.style.display = "block";
          videoElement.srcObject = stream;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("No se pudo acceder a la cámara: ", error);
        });
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Mostrar cámara</h1>
  <div id="camera"></div>

  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      initializeCamera();
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No solamente no nos gustan las respuestas de las IA (que para colmo, vos no podes validar porque no la escribiste) si no, que ni siquiera entendiste la pregunta, que es como compartir pantalla, no como encender la camara...